# How to prevent bend (or warping) with M3D printer?

Tags: warping

Hello is there a way to prevent bend on print with M3D printer?

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information...  What material are you printing, is the bed heated, if so what is the bed temperature, do you have anything on the bed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to print a brim, a thin layer on the bottom connected to the model. This will help hold it in place. Since it is thin (one or two layers) it will not warp itself.

The brim is not the same thing as a raft. A raft is under the model. The brim is on the same layer as the models bottom layer but outside the model. It looks something like this:

[image: brim]

I assume that you use a heated bed if you have one?

Also, it is imperative that you get a good first layer. Calibrate your machine carefully.

Comment: Do you mean like a raft? I already did that and still it warps on top of the raft

Comment: @xybrek I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Going to also say you need to provide us with a ton more information. What settings, what temps, what plastic.

That said the best thing I can recommend is doing a Raft for your print. Adding a Fan to your printer. Making sure your heated bed is on. I also like to use gluesticks for PLA, hairspray or Kapton for ABS.

[Here is Ultimakers guide to Gluesticks](https://ultimaker.com/en/resources/16968-using-glue)

[Here is a guide on rafts and Brims from simplify 3d](https://www.simplify3d.com/support/articles/rafts-skirts-and-brims/)

Comment on my answer once you provide more information and I will improve my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try using an adhesive before you print. This could be http://airwolf3d.com/shop/wolfbite-prevents-3d-printed-parts-from-warping ... What is the temperature of the room you are printing in like?